# Is nvim's documentation corrupting my windows installation?

Tags: neovim, vim-windows

I recently decided to try out nvim, after using vim for a few years. I started following [these instructions](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim)

I noticed after running these two commands

```
:call mkdir(stdpath('config'), 'p')
:exe 'edit '.stdpath('config').'/init.vim'
```

I can no longer launch a specific app on my machine without it hard crashing (0xc0000409 -- STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN)

If it's any use, this is my nvim.init

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath = &runtimepath
source ~/vimfiles/vimrc
source ~/vimfiles/gvimrc
```

I'm wondering if one of these commands is malformed and somehow [corrupting my systems registry key](https://www.minitool.com/news/0xc0000409.html) or something of the sort?
I noticed this happen on two separate machines now, both close in time to when I ran these commands, so I'm fairly certain my nvim configuring has something to do with it.

Has anyone else run into this? Or have any guesses as to what might be happening?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I strongly encourage you to also reach out the neovim dev team/community if you have not already done so.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another dev from my company experienced the same crash a few days later. So I don't believe my nvim configuring had anything to do with it.